# How to find the general term of this recurrence?

Tags: recurrence-relations

> $$\displaystyle a(n,r) = a(n,r-1) + a(n-1,r)$$

for $n,r >1$. Given that $a(1,0) = a(0,1) = 1$.

Comment: hold on, what about $a(0,2)$ is it defned?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clearly $a(n,r)$ is the number of ways to get from $(0,0)$ to $(n,r)$ by only moving one unit up or right on the lattice plain. So we have $a(n,r)=\binom{n+r}{n}$

Comment: How would you derive such a relation?

Comment: well, the recurrences are the same.

Comment: Yes, I know that but I mean how would you do this systematically?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have experience solving $2$-dimensional recurrences systematically. You mean something like a g.f approach?

Comment: Nevermind, I found out how to solve this algorithmically. Btw nice intuition.

Comment: @MrYouMath does your german have an accent? I learned german a couple of years back and I wasnt sure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51620/discussion-between-mryoumath-and-jorge-fernandez-hidalgo).